# Go not making binary using GoClipse

Tags: eclipse, macos, go, osx-mavericks, goclipse

Installed GoClipse v0.80 into Eclipse Luna on OS X Mavericks...

Set the following values inside Eclipse's Preferences --> Go:

GOROOT: /usr/local/go
GOPATH: /DevProjects/Go/GoHello (this has a src folder underneath it)

I created a Go project (along with new Go file) and put the following code inside src/Hello.go:

```
package src

import "fmt"

func main() {
     fmt.Println("Hello")
}
```

When I run Hello.go, inside the Eclipse Console this what appears:

```
************  Running Go build for project: GoHello  ************
************  Build terminated.  ************
```

How coming its not printing Hello to stdout?

Comment: Is there no other output from the build?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need `package main`:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
     fmt.Println("Hello")
}
```

Output:

```
Hello
```

---

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Program execution](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Program_execution)
>
> A complete program is created by linking a single, unimported package
>   called the `main` package with all the packages it imports,
>   transitively. The `main` package must have package name `main` and declare
>   a function `main` that takes no arguments and returns no value.
>
> ```
> func main() { … }
> ```
>
> Program execution begins by initializing the `main` package and then
>   invoking the function `main`. When that function invocation returns, the
>   program exits. It does not wait for other (non-`main`) goroutines to
>   complete.

Comment: Wow. Apparently I'm blind today. +1.

Comment: Thank you! Yeah, I am blind too... Now, it works... Its my Java background that made me type in src instead of main for the package declaration. Thanks to both of you, peterSO & Simon!